# Is my revised Cynocephali race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, races

The race of dog men returns for a version two that aims to have more interesting abilities that don't skew to paladins or rogues that much!

- **Ability Scores:** Your Dexterity score increases by 2 and your Strength score increases by 1.
- **Size:** Cynocephali are tall, reaching up 7 feet in height. Your size is Medium.
- **Speed:** Your base walking speed is 30 feet
- **Darkvision.**  You have superior vision in dark and dim conditions. You can see in dim light within 60 feet of you as if it were bright light, and in darkness as if it were dim light. You can't discern color in darkness, only shades of gray.
- **Bite.** 1d4 + Strength or Dexterity
- **Canine Tactics.** When you hit a creature with an attack on your turn, you can use your bonus action to take the Help action. You can use this trait a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest. When you take the Help action in this way, you can help two creatures instead of one.
- **Mark the Scent.** As a bonus action, you can mark one creature you can see within 10 feet of you. Until the end of your next long rest, your proficiency bonus is doubled for any ability check you make to find the marked creature, and you always know the location of that creature if it is within 60 feet of you. You can use this trait a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.
- **Keen Senses.** You have proficiency in the Perception skill.
- **Languages.** You can speak, read and write Common and Canine. In addition, you can communicate simple concepts to wolves and dogs when you speaks in Canine.

---

This is the revision, the original can be found [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196729/is-this-cynocephali-race-balanced)

Comment: Can you clarify what 'help two creatures' means? I assume it means you pick two allies that can use the Help bonus?

Comment: @Erik Exactly though I don't know how to word it better

Comment: I like Canine Tactics, similar to the hobgoblin Fey Gift.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, it is balanced

I will look at the race using Build Points (from Kamstra’s [monstrous races](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/230312/Monstrous-Races)), with one build point roughly equating +1 ASI. The recommended total for a race is 8-10.

***Ability Score Increase.*** 3 build points. Keep in mind that modern convention with ability score increases is +2 to any, +1 to any.

***Darkvision.*** 2 BP. Not entirely sure if this ability makes sense for dogs, but basically every race has it so *shrug*.

***Bite.*** 1 BP. Keep in mind that innate attack Damage dice have been standardized to 1d6 in Monsters of the Multiverse.

***Canine Tactics.*** 1.5 BP. Granting advantage to two creatures as a bonus action is a pretty good ability: I will call it roughly on par with a 1st level spell.

***Mark the Scent.*** As is, .5 BP. I would suggest considering just granting Hunter’s Mark 1/long rest. It fits what you are trying to do, and still wouldn’t overpower the race.

This brings our total to 8 BP. Consider the suggestions I made, but overall, it is a well balanced and flavourful race.

Comment: Dogs have pretty good nightvision!